# There are no commands defined in the "make:fixtures" namespace

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fixtures

After using this command:

```
php bin/console make:fixtures:load
```

I receive this error:

> There are no commands defined in the "make:fixtures" namespace.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because this format have a better readability and your NB was useless for the question itself (_also the error was originated from a simple user error_).

Comment: @gp_sflower Yes, I'm starting, so I don't know particle nothing yet on Symfony. Do you think I should delete the question?

Comment: Welcome Jeremy! in general I don't think it is a good pratice to delete an answered question (_in my opinion_) but before to post your future questions, take some time to read the [Help Section](https://stackoverflow.com/help), on where you will find many really useful tips to also learn how to identify and closely inspecting [the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, more a question is good and more interest it will attract and more faster you will have a solution to your problem ;-).

Comment: @gp_sflover Thank you very much for your advice. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to load the fixtures is:

```
doctrine:fixtures:load
```

To make a fixture, however, is:

```
make:fixture
```

Answer (score 6):

Be sure to use "dev" environment.

If needed, edit your environment file : .env.local

```
###> symfony/framework-bundle ###
APP_ENV=dev
```

This message often appears when environment is set to "prod".

You can also edit config/bundles.php to allow (at your own risk) doctrine fixtures to be used in "prod" environment :

```
Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```